# stringByReplacingOccurrence does not replace string

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing, nsfilemanager

I need to parse a FILE URL in my application, and replace the %20 for a SPACE. I am using stringByReplacingOccurance:

```
NSString *strippedContent = [finalFilePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];
```

But when I display strippedContent in an NSLog, all of the %20 strings are still there. Here is an example of the file name I hope to parse:

```
.../Documents/Inbox/Test%20Doc%20From%20Another%20App.txt
```

It seems as if NSFileManager cannot find the document when it has the %20 in it.
The file path is being passed from another application through the "Open In..." dialogue. Is there any way to remove the %20 with stringByReplacingOccurrence or when the URL is imported?

Comment: I tried this code         NSString *finalFilePath = @".../Documents/Inbox/Test%20Doc%20From%20Another%20App.txt";
        NSString *strippedContent = [finalFilePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"%@", strippedContent);  I got the output ".../Documents/Inbox/Test Doc From Another App.txt"

Comment: I think your code works correctly..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`NSString` provides a method that performs the conversion that you need:

```
NSString *strippedContent = [finalFilePath stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: It should be noted this ONLY removes the Percent symbols, and they will have to perform another pass using the NSString *strippedContent = [finalFilePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"20" withString:@""];

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should use:

```
NSString * strippedContent = [finalFilePath stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: He wants to remove the percent escapes, not add them.

Comment: @ Evan Mulawski sorry, fixed it

Comment: @self - What is the difference b/w your and `@dasblinkenlight` answer ?